# Ruby on Rails: loading seed data from a YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I use a YAML file instead of seeds.rb to load the initial data into a database?

Comment: Seeing as the accepted answer is not great (puts seed data in `test/` directory), and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24957205/405550) has significantly more upvotes, would you please consider accepting mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Ruby on Rails Guide to fixtures:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Generally, you can create YAML fixture files in the `test/` directory and then load them into your database using the `rake db:fixtures:load` command. The full documentation on all the cool things you can do with fixtures is here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html

Comment: The last link is broken. Also, loading seed data from `test/` doesn't seem like the right way of doing things.

Comment: It makes me feel uncomfortable as well, but in practice some people use fixtures to populate data for testing purposes. Having the same yaml seeding files in two places feels even more...icky.

Comment: My answer was from 6 years ago, and I think the world has changed significantly. The higher-voted answer is definitely better, but I personally have moved to using the Seedbank gem: https://github.com/james2m/seedbank

Answer (score 26):

Add code in `db/seeds.rb` to parse the YAML file, e.g.:

```
seed_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', 'categories.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
Category.create!(config)
```

Then, simply place the YAML fie in `db/seeds/categories.yml`. The YAML file should be a list of associative arrays, e.g.:

```
- name: accessory
  shortcode: A

- name: laptop
  shortcode: L

- name: server
  shortcode: S
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you run `rake db:seed` a second time, you'll get a bunch of duplicates. Depending on the requirements for uniqueness, you'll probably want to modify the last line to be something like: `config.each {|values| Category.first_or_create(values) }`

Comment: In what situation would you want to seed the database twice? `rake db:reset` does everything you need 99% of the time.

Comment: If you add new seeded values to the table or add a new table with seeded values. Dropping the whole database might be a solution in a development environment, but certainly isn't in production. Dropping the seeded table before re-seeding is also not an option if there are any references to that table's ids in another table. If you need to remove previously seeded values the situation gets even more complicated and may require a solution beyond `rake db:seed`.

Comment: @sberkley consider using https://github.com/harrystech/seed_migration. This is a tool that makes management of seeding similar to the standard rake db:seed. The command is `rake seed:migrate` (and rollback). Within the seed migration, you can do the standard yaml file load in the various answers here.

Answer (score 5):

I used the answer @Zaz answered. It works very well.

But in the meanwhile if something went wrong with your seed data(For example you have a very large seed yaml file), you would like to know which part of your yaml went wrong. At that time you can add a block after create! for debug like this:

```
seed_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', 'categories.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
counter = 0
Category.create!(config) do |c|
  puts "Create category #{counter += 1} with name: #{c.name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I built this script to handle exactly this issue, while keeping seeds yaml files separate to tests.

It has namespace support, and will automatically find records when you supply just an id

https://gist.github.com/x9sim9/78405f13b698b87ab7b234ea793399ca