# Seed.rb in Ruby on Rails for creating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, hash, seed

I have two classes: Article(has_many comments) and Comment(belongs_to article). My database is empty, postgresql.
I need download information in db from seeds.yml using seed.rb. Code in seeds.rb must contain class HashWithIndifferentAccess.
I'm newbie in RoR and I cannot find some good information about it.

Comment: Seems like this post is duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986463/ruby-on-rails-loading-seed-data-from-a-yaml-file)

Comment: @OscarLuza , if am I right... this is a little different. They don't use the class  HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Comment: please provide the code you have ATM and ask a question about it