# How to generate a db/seed.rb file from text fixtures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I've been googling around about this, but can't seem to find a straightforward answer.

I have a bunch of fixtures inside text/fixtures and I was wondering if there is a way to automatically generate a db/seed.rb file from these fixtures (say for manual testing on a Heroku staging site).

I'd like the data in my fixtures and seeds to be the same. This seems like it should be fairly straightforward in rails.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986463/ruby-on-rails-loading-seed-data-from-a-yaml-file) post is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use a yaml file for my database seeds, but I was wondering if there's a way to use my fixtures file for my test fixtures and also generate a database seeds file. So instead of having fixtures and seeds, just fixtures to create the seeds. Is there a good reason Rails has both fixtures and seeds? For my app I really don't see the need for them to be different.